# Can Fibonacci Heap have more than one nodes with equal rank(or value, or key)?

Tags: algorithm, heap, computer-science, fibonacci-heap

I am studying Fibonacci heap alone, and I came across a question.

I know any nodes can be inserted into Fibonacci heap, but what if the rank(or value, or key) of that new node is equal to the sibling node?

1) For example,

```
   (1) <-minimum root
  /   \
(3)   (5)
```

and what happens if node of (1) is inserted?

```
(1) --- (1)
       /   \
     (3)   (5)
```

2) Or what happens in this kind of situation?

**before:**

```
 (2)-----(4)-----(5)
  |      / \     / \
 (1)   (6) (7) (8) (9)
```

**after:**

```
 (2)-----(4)-----(5)    +     (5)
  |              / \          / \
 (1)           (8) (9)      (1) (2)
```

Where would the new node-tree belong?

3) How would you consolidate(or order) this kind of tree - that has a pair of equal nodes at the root?

```
 (10) ---- (10) ----- (1) ----- (3) ----- (4)
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me solve this little confusion on Fibonacci heap. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes with equal keys are OK.

Recall the *heap property*: for **min-heap**, the key of each node is **greater than** ***or equal to*** the key of its parent. (The max-heap property can similarly defined.)

A Fibonacci heap is just a collection of such trees. If more than one root has the minimum key, then any such root can be the **minimum node**.

In you are examples, there's nothing wrong with (1) and (3). But in (2), you have trees that violate the min-heap property.